# Svelte store's get method lookup performance

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component, svelte-store

I have a Svelte app where most of the data logic is extracted into files that define custom stores. Often, I will need to write a function that uses the same store value repeatedly:

```js
import { get } from 'svelte/store';
import { someStore } from './myStores';

function foo(): void {
   const arr: string[] = get(someStore);
   // ...lots of operations using arr
}
```

My current practice is that if I only need the value of `someStore` once, I'll just use `get(someStore)` inline, but if I need it at least twice in that function I'll assign it to a local variable like above. This is because I'm not sure whether calling `get` over and over again would be bad for performance.

Does anyone who understands how Svelte stores are implemented have any intuition as to whether this is really necessary? Would I suffer any performance problems if I simplified my code to just use `get(...)` everywhere instead of creating local constants (I'm not really concerned about reactive behavior changing the returned value mid-function)? What about if the store's value is a very large object?

Comment: From where are you calling the function? Why not pass the store value as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Svelte documentation on 'get'](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-get):

> Generally, you should read the value of a store by subscribing to it
> and using the value as it changes over time. Occasionally, you may
> need to retrieve the value of a store to which you're not subscribed.
> get allows you to do so.

And (bolded for emphasis):

> **This works by creating a subscription, reading the value, then unsubscribing. It's therefore not recommended in hot code paths.**

So, from a pure performance standpoint, as soon as you plan on using `get` more than once, you would be better off simply subscribing to the store - meaning accessing the value directly as `$someStore` using the shorthand syntax. However, if you're not interested in keeping your local data synced to the store updates, or even worse, if you specifically do not *want* to, then your approach looks perfectly fine.

In practice, however, you could simply do:

```js
import { someStore } from './myStores';

function foo(): void {
   const arr: string[] = $someStore;
   // ...lots of operations using arr
}
```

and save yourself the extra import. And if you do not care if the value of the store changes, or if you *want* to keep up with the changes, then you can save yourself the assignment and use `$someStore` in lieu of `arr` (or whatever variable you assigned the store value to).

Comment: Given the case that the function is inside a component "*Auto-subscription only works with store variables that are declared (or imported) at the top-level scope of a component.*"

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question I'd say. And to clarify my use case, a lot of my usage of store values is happening outside components inside various CRUD utility functions that are shared between components.

Comment: I don't understand why svelte tells you "don't use get(), use subscribe" and then uses "$store" everywhere inline in the HTML examples, which is just shorthand for get(store)? I assume it actually subscribes in the generated code...but for ".js" helper libraries it's super awkward.